# Not able to verify hashed password

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I'm using SHA-512 to encrypt passwords. I think that I'm doing everything correctly (and even duplicating code that is successful elsewhere), but every time I try to enter a password, it fails to match what I have stored in my database.

```
$sql = "SELECT hashed_password FROM Users WHERE user_name='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$db_password = mysql_result($result, 0);

if (crypt($currentPlaintext, $db_password) != $db_password) {
    echo "Your current password is incorrect.";
    die();
}
```

I have verified the following obvious potential problems and eliminated them as causes:

1) There is an encrypted password stored in my database

2) I am able to retrieve this password and store it in the variable $db_password

3) The variables $username and $currentPlaintext do have the correct values as passed over by my ajax function call.

So, why isn't this working? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the comments so far. To clarify, as I understand the crypt() function, the second argument of crypt is actually the entire string that is stored in the db. This string includes not only the hashed password, but also the algorithm, salt value, and number of rounds of hashing. The crypt() function is supposed to pull the salt value out of this string and then apply it to hash the first argument. The result is then compared to the previously hashed password. That's why this is so confusing. I don't have to give it a salt value - the salt is there in the database. Am I misunderstanding what is going on in this function?

I originally hashed the password with this code:

```
$salt = uniqid();
$algo = '6';
$rounds = '5000';
$cryptSalt = '$' . $algo . '$rounds=' . $rounds . '$' . $salt;
$hashedPassword = crypt($plaintext, $cryptSalt);
```

Comment: Maybe that you're using the encrypted password from your DB as the salt? See [`crypt`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: It's best to use a trusted external source for one way encryption. One I have found useful: https://github.com/SlayerSolutions/Authentication/blob/master/Downloads/Version%202%20%28Class%29.php OR  https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib

Comment: to give a meaningful answer you need to know how the hashed_password came into the db, how was it hashed? and do you know wether crypt() will actually hash the currentPlaintext password the same way you did for generating hashed_password in the first place?
So, summing up, there is to little information about how you handle hashing to give a meaningful answer

Answer (score 0):

You check if

```
crypt($plaintext, $pass) == $pass
```

Looking at the crypt manual you see that the second argument of crypt is `$salt`. So you need to give it the salt you used when you created the hash. If you do not use a salt (which you should be doing), then try to remove this second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using Sha512? Depending on the system crypt() might use a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The `crypt` function in PHP doesn't necessarily return an SHA512 hash.

Use `hash('sha512', $currentPlaintext)` instead.